# Superfish sub menu above menu

Tags: jquery, superfish

I have a working superfish navbar, but I would like the sub menu to popup and not down because of my theme requires it. The superfish navbar example can be seen [here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/nav-bar/).

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the css code and if you change top:100% to bottom:100% in the .sf-menu ul section then it will work.

```
.sf-menu ul {
    bottom:100%;
    display:none;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
}
```